# Provide me a more elegant way for this if else- statement

Tags: java, if-statement

This looks clumsy and I know theres a more elegant way, but I dont know how it's called:

```
if (a.isSelected()) {
    a.setSelected(false);
}

else {
    a.setSelected(true);
}
```

How do I make this leaner?

Comment: Suitable for http://programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You can move the condition into the function parameters like this: `a.setSelected( a.isSelected()? false : true )` and then simplify to this `a.setSelected( !a.isSelected() )`

Comment: Also find out how your IDE allows you to reformat code.  In Eclipse it is <key>Ctrl-Alt-F</key>.  That alone may help a lot.

Comment: why is this question downvoted? i think it's a clear and clean question related to programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
a.setSelected(!a.isSelected());
```

with the `!` you can just negotiate your `boolean` expression. So the `true` becomes `false` and the other way round, like you wanted to achieve in your code.

Answer (score 5):

You can do like:

```
a.setSelected(!a.isSelected());
```

Answer (score 1):

You should analyse the conditions and the steps that you are doing.

In your case:

```
Condition    Output
true         false
false        true
```

This will show you that all you are doing is `!(condition)`. So that should give you the idea.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
a.setSelected(!a.isSelected());
```